# Dataset/Datatable to Excel Template File .net

Tags: .net, excel

I know there are a lot of questions on how to write data from a dataset or datatable to excel, but they all seem to assume a new blank excel workbook. I have a special excel file containing multiple sheets with lots of formatting, formulas, and a chart. I just need to lay data over the appropriate portions of some sheets and let excel handle the rest.

So I need a way to insert data into an existing excel file, at a certain range (which can vary depending on the number of rows), on certain sheets. Currently I'm using the COM interop to write it all which is a performance nightmare and needs to be changed. So what would be the best way to accomplish this?

More info: We have a simple mvc app that lets the user submit a request for data. It kicks off this console app as a seperate process to get the data and build the excel file. So first we get the data which takes 10-15 seconds, then we write the data to excel. It's the actual writing of the values to the cell that appears to be taking all the time. **Whether the formulas in the excel file are having an affect on the write I don't know**, but that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Update: As it turns out the formulas were the primary hindarence on the speed of the writes. I set the Calculation property of the Excel Application class to XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual and it runs much faster now! This isn't the proper answer to my question but it's what worked.

Thank you to shahkalpesh who did point this out, and Cj!

Thank you,
Jeff

Comment: Is formulas & updating of charts, while cells are being written causing the performance to go down? ScreenUpdating?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I'm not writing formulas, just data, but yes the writing to excel in general is what's slow. There is no screen update since we send it to the user as an email afterwards. I've added that though to help clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff: What I mean is that sometimes there are complex formulas and/or chart(s) depending upon a few values input by user. And then it does the calculation and refreshing of excel workbook UI which takes time. Could that be a problem in your case? To solve some of your problem, write code in a VB6 based component or executable and let it do the job dealing with excel.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Well I don't think that is it because there is no UI. I'm generating the data for the file, the user input is only used to get the data for the file, and the data that is written is just text and numbers. So I don't think that is the problem, it's just a lot of writes (maybe 20-100 writes/row and 100's of rows so 1000's or 10,000's of writes to cells).

Comment: Here is a link that talks about using COM with Excel.  Looks like there are some performance tweaks you could try: http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop

Comment: @Cj: Interesting link. I appreciate your answer too but this link may be the best since I am reading using .Cells[row,col] which according to the link is a bad idea. I'm actually going to give a try at removing the reading altogether and see how much that helps. Thank you Cj!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same thing.  COM Interop can be a pain... I don't know your entire situation but you could simply export the datatable to XML.  (Datatable.WriteXML)  Then use VBA to suck the data in and do the parsing.  It'd be cleaner to use all .NET but VBA is fast would probably be pretty fast.

Aside from that I swear there was a nice free library out there that would simplify working in Excel for .NET.  I don't know what type of performance there is....  Another option is VSTO ([VSTO Development Home](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx))  which depending on what you want to do might be a good fit as well.  Good luck!

Update: Here you go this is what I was looking for:  [File Helper](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you insert a DataTable into an existing workbook, fixing up formulas and formatting appropriately - without resorting to COM Interop.

See the **DataTable to Excel Workbook with Formats and Formulas** sample on [this page](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/datagrid.aspx) for a live ASP.NET example with C# and VB source.

You can see more live ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

In VBA with ADO you'd use ;

```
sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs, 65536
```

which is much faster than whiling through the recordset. Is there a similar VSTO method?